# Outlook 2010 strange chars

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010

From one of my customer i am receiving contents of the email with really strange look-like chars like this:

> KierujÄ™ siÄ™ do PaÅ„stwa w sprawie

However when i open email on my htc smart phone message seems to be fine, so seems it belongs to outlook internal issue and not message itself. Do you know how to fix it?

Comment: Try changing the display font.

Comment: @DavidPostill: That looks like a problem with encoding, not with fonts.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft Yeah, could be. It looks like Polish anyway.

Comment: yes it's polish. Where to change it? Thanks.